# Can't parse the token along with special characters like (+) we get from URL params in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting automatically generated token along with url like mentioned below:

```
https://localhost:3000/?token=ebkfJu12VQpfwX3YwAMo7PZoGYJftaMisMcL6VeNSz8IUmaywH64U2k6l8KFCblWXZfPbd9oJSshcwo/6p6cPrMtifFOXfduJbKTeitJqpIwAsq4CpaagGHdZpluUlDSsVlS2KoYQBS/XqxTcSLq+iS4wUWNpKYH8z7w9Vzs7AYPOZEFixSIslP9amBZWtTSIOi/NZkNheYJPRLHun6gHGRZTBAgp8y/6jPvCyjS8HCgqscEqhNponeGoazJAVZuxE1syphiv4EBkjigLIbDl2IoN77shBWwEgojmvmo8UuhV8WhnziXQQrdJU1nirjgCIJ84jxn5d+fjqQC0xfSJQ==
```

Since this token contains +, hence at the time of parsing `const params = new URLSearchParams(tokenString);` + is replaced by spaces. How to get the token untouched?

The output I am expecting is

```
{
  token: 'ebkfJu12VQpfwX3YwAMo7PZoGYJftaMisMcL6VeNSz8IUmaywH64U2k6l8KFCblWXZfPbd9oJSshcwo/6p6cPrMtifFOXfduJbKTeitJqpIwAsq4CpaagGHdZpluUlDSsVlS2KoYQBS/XqxTcSLq+iS4wUWNpKYH8z7w9Vzs7AYPOZEFixSIslP9amBZWtTSIOi/NZkNheYJPRLHun6gHGRZTBAgp8y/6jPvCyjS8HCgqscEqhNponeGoazJAVZuxE1syphiv4EBkjigLIbDl2IoN77shBWwEgojmvmo8UuhV8WhnziXQQrdJU1nirjgCIJ84jxn5d+fjqQC0xfSJQ=='
}
```

Comment: Encode the token using `encodeURIComponent` first?

Comment: Already encoded url params from the frontend and decoded in the backend